# How to scheduling hadoop map tasks in different node cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a only map program which have more than 10 maps. My cluster have 5 nodes, my question is: can I scheduling running which map tasks to which node? For example, let No.1 map running in node1, No.3 map running in node3 and No.9 map running in node5.
If I can do so, then what change in my code and configuration file is needed. By the way, I use HDFS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Affinity can't be set in the Hadoop for the map task to node mapping. The scheduler automatically decides based on the data locality/slot status where to run a Map task.