# Core affinity of Map Tasks in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, affinity

**Question:** Does Hadoop v.1.2.1 or v.2 (YARN) offer a way to determine core affinity, of different Map Tasks, within a single job? In other words, can I pin a specific Map Task to a specific core, in a similar way to Linux's `taskset`, or is it out of hadoop's control and up to the Linux Scheduler?

I am relatively new to Map Reduce programming and my project involves studying its performance when different parameters (machine- or network-specific) are altered. I have so far undergone through its official documentation (v.1.2.1) and numerous threads both online and Stack Exchange.

Below I'm providing two different cases, to better illustrate my question, along with my so-far research.

---

**Example #1:** Suppose I have the following configuration:

- Input: 2 GiB
- HDFS block size: 64 MiB
- Data nodes: 2 nodes x 32 cores (processors)
- No Reduce Tasks are required.

According to the block size, 2 GiB / 64 MiB = 32 Map Tasks will be called. If `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` is set to `16` then exactly 16 Map tasks will be run on node #1 and 16 will run on node  #2, with 16 cores per node to spare. (links: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373498/how-to-schedule-hadoop-map-tasks-in-multi-core-8-node-cluster), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707106/how-to-make-hadoop-use-all-the-cores-on-my-system))

As far as I have found, there is no way to directly control "node" affinity, i.e., how to map "Map tasks" to specific nodes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647815/how-to-scheduling-hadoop-map-tasks-in-different-node-cluster/15660806#15660806)), apart from its "Rack awareness" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970044/how-to-specify-individual-tasktrackersnodes-on-which-a-mapreduce-should-run/15973447#15973447)). However, within a *specific* node, may I...

**Question #1:** ... "pin" each Map Task to a specific core?
**Question #2:** ... guarantee that each Map Task will *stay* on the core it started on? Or is it out of hadoop's control and dependent on the Linux Scheduler?

---

**Example #2:** suppose Example #1's configuration, but with an input size of 8 GiB, resulting in 128 Map Tasks.

**Question #1:** regardless of the value of `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`, will the 128 Map Tasks be called simultaneously? Is it correct that, since I have in total 64 Map slots (over 2x nodes), each node will on average handle 2x Map Tasks per core?

**Question #2:** if Question #1 is correct, do I have any control (within a single node) over "how much time" a Map Task will stay on a single core and if it will be reallocated to the same core, or is it out of hadoop's control and up to the Linux Scheduler?

---

Concerning the **reduce tasks**, I assume that the related answers would hold, as well, i.e., core affinity would be also possible (or not).

Comment: Nice question there... and very crucial to understand it for better performance of hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper provides some insight on task-core affinity - [On the Core Affinity and File Upload Performance of Hadoop](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829000039/http://home.konkuk.ac.kr/%7Ejinh/papers/jin_discs13.pdf)

The paper mentions that POSIX standard defines `sched_setaffnity()` system call to decide the process(or task in this case) to core affinity at the user level.

But I would appreciate an easier way to define task-core affinity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! If I understand correctly, I have to start my hadoop job and run externally `sched_setaffinity()` on the **CPU-intensive threads**, to **pin** them on a specific core, right? I've seen that I can easily find these threads by running `ps -emo %cpu,pid,user,args | sort -rnk 1 | grep "java" | head | awk '{print $1, $2}'`.  Btw, the [link](http://home.konkuk.ac.kr/~jinh/papers/jin_discs13.pdf) is malformed in your original answer.